# How to derive velocity out of acceleration in a circular motion?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

A car **starts** moving in a circle with a radius of 200 meters. It has a constant tangential acceleration of $1{\text{m}\over {\text{sec}}^{2}}$.

a. What is the angular acceleration?

b. What is the angular velocity of the car 10 seconds after it started to drive?

Attempt: a. If the velocity grows by 1 meter per second, then it grows by $1\over 2\pi R$ radians(?) per second and I should just convert the radians to angels.(?).
As for b, I am not sure at all. I am not sure about a. either. I could really use any help or guidance.

Comment: Although this does fit here in a technical sense, this seems a better fit for [physics.se] to me.

Comment: I never knew there was one for physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear acceleration is radius multiplied by angular acceleration, and angular acceleration is measured in radians per second per second.
For part b) you can adapt the appropriate "suvat" equation to angular displacement since angular acceleration is constant.

Comment: Is 1 the linear acceleration(I am not sure if tangential and linear are the same), and if so, then is the angular acceleration $1\over 200$?

Comment: @Meitar Yes to both!